# Custom tabs build with vss-web-extension-sdk not showing anymore

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

We have build an Azure Devops Extension that does several things within a step of a pipeline. When a pipeline is finished and results are displayed we coded it to show additional custom tabs, we used the [vss-web-extension-sdk](https://github.com/Microsoft/vss-web-extension-sdk) for adding these custom tabs to the results.

As of June 1st 2020 for unknown reasons those tabs do not appear anymore. There appear no additional details on why not (we did debugging in the developer consoles, no errors, no info logs). Normally we would at a minimal see some loading of additional pages and scripts for those custom tabs.

We did notice that a new update came out for [Azure DeveOps in sprint 170 on June 1st](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-170-update) but there are no mentions of potentially deprecating the use of the [vss-web-extension-sdk](https://github.com/Microsoft/vss-web-extension-sdk).

We also checked the github pages below to see if anything got deprecated:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/vss-web-extension-sdk
- https://github.com/microsoft/vsts-extension-samples

As code reference, we make the tabs visible by adding their details to the manifest as so:

```
{
    "manifestVersion": 1,
    "id": "someid"
    ...
    "contributions": [
       {
           "id": "someid-report-hub",
           "type": "ms.vss-build-web.build-results-tab",
           "targets": [
               "ms.vss-build-web.build-results-view"
           ],
           "properties": {
               "name": "Somename Build Report",
               "uri": "build/somereport.html"
           }
       }
    ]
}
```

Additionally to doing research on what could be causing this we tested:

- In our Cloud Azure DevOps solution, we created a new test extension to just using the [vsts-extension-samples](https://github.com/microsoft/vsts-extension-samples) and this was still not showing the custom tabs.
- In our on prem Azure DevOps server, which doesn't have the June 1st update, we can still see the custom tabs of our extension.

Any thoughts/help on what could be happing would be appreciated.

Comment: Just noticed it was also found/reported here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1061194/build-result-tabs-msvss-build-webbuild-results-tab.html

Comment: Waited several days before commenting, just to confirm, but it appears this is not an issue anymore. Likely due to the Visual Studio team looking at it (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1061194/build-result-tabs-msvss-build-webbuild-results-tab.html).

Comment: Can you please let me know how you developed the custom tab? I also have a similar requirement and my test results are stored in artifacts.

Comment: @SormitaChakraborty I started initially with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/get-started/node?view=azure-devops there are several How To Guides there.

Comment: I have also followed the same tutorial but I am not able to get the .html in my extension to get populated with json stored in my build artifacts. Can you please help me out there with some sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marked as fixed by Microsoft

See https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1061194/build-result-tabs-msvss-build-webbuild-results-tab.html

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT thanks for that, completely forgot, done!